# R: assign a value in a upper-level function

Tags: r

Probably a simple question, but I can't figure it out myself, working with environments and scoping still confuse me.

I have a function, nested in a function. What I am trying to achieve is to assign a value (using the `assign` function, I have read that using `<<-` can be dangerous) from the nested function in its parent and use it there:

```
myfun <- function(m) {
  m*3*y
  f1 <- function() {
    assign(x = y, value = 2, envir = parent.frame())
  }
  f1()
}
```

However, error is returned:

```
Error in myfun(m = 5) : object 'y' not found
```

In addition, what if I have a function, nested in a function, nested in a function, nested in a function, etc., and I want to choose in which upper level to assign the value from the lowest level function?

Comment: What is variable `y` in `function(m)`?

Comment: @Carles Mitjans: `y` takes the value of 2, defined in function `f1`.

Comment: In the first line of `myfun` where `m*3*y`, `y` is not defined, that's why you get that error.

Comment: @Carles Mitjans: `myfun` is just a simple example, not really what I am working on. What I try to achieve with it is to pass a variable defined in a function nested in `myfun`. Kota Mori already pointed my mistake, it was the order in defining the nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points.  You need to run `f1()` before you compute with `y`.  `x` argument of `assign` function takes character.

```
myfun <- function(m) {
  f1 <- function() {
  assign(x = "y", value = 2, envir = parent.frame())
  }
  f1()
  m*3*y
}

myfun(5)
```